# Is there a way to collaborate on the same Worksheet in Snowflake, for example create a template similar to how they work in SQL Server?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm one of several analyst and data engineers working within a Snowflake database. We all often have to write ad-hoc small bits of code to check tables and views. These are often quite repetitive tasks (e.g. filtering data based on a certain reference, joining FACTS and DIM tables to add context).

I'd like to create a Worksheet that we can all periodically add useful bits of code to. Just to save us time making joins or be a good starting place for writing longer bits of code.

I've previously used SQL Server where I was able to save template files with useful bits of code. I could open these files directly within SQL Server so it was really easy to open, edit and run these files. What are some similar features in Snowflake?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must use the new web UI "snowsight". In the new UI you can share worksheets with team members and give them edit access. You can also import your worksheets from the classic UI as well.

Keep in mind that team editing doesn't work like google docs, where you can see each other typing. So be mindful of that. However, every version of the worksheet is automatically saved and available from the upper right of the interface.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-gs.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-worksheets-gs.html